# Get (web) url for help documentation in R?

Tags: r

When opening help docs within RStudio with something like `?"function"`, how can we (easily) get the web version of these help docs?

Currently I look for a unique-ish sentence and google it with quotes. For example, to find the web version of `?"function"`, I googled `"These functions provide the base mechanisms for defining new functions in the R language."` - but there must be something more efficient?

Comment: Is it that you want to open the existing help page in a browser like Firefox, or you want a fully-online version (i.e. to send to someone who doesn't have R or that package installed)?

Comment: @Any url would be fine. So I run something like `helpDocsFor('function')` and it returns `https://www.cran.com/helpdocs/function` (that's a made up url, obviously a placeholder for some url with the exact same docs as seen in R/Rstudio when `?` is used to view docs

Comment: Could you provide an example of a URL you'd like to reach? There's not an official source for those, which is most of the problem. Most packages on CRAN have the help pages in a downloadable PDF, but I don't think you want to go there. One could write a custom function for building URLs for rdocumentation.org, perhaps...

Comment: And it would be good to understand your goal in this---as Martin Morgan shows, it's pretty easy to open your local help file in a browser other than RStudio. If that's not what you want, **why** do you want to open an online copy? If you're looking for a more updated source, then building an rdocumentation.org URL gets harder because it includes the package version in the URL. Understanding *why* you want to do this will help get a better answer.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- Good questions. I'm after a www URL to the docs so that I can write about R and the reader (not necessarily running R) can read the docs via a link.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- I can see now using `?` provides the docs from R without RStudio, and without an internet connection. Meaning those docs are included with R (I think). All I'm after is a quick and easy way to get the equivalent www URL to those same docs, so I can link to it

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- I think you're right about constructing the URL. We can get the R version easily enough. I wonder how we can get the mapping from, say, `[` to `extract`, so that docsURL('[')` would return https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Extract (correct) and not https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/[ (incorrect)

Comment: Martin Morgan's answer still gets you most of the way there. Using his code, `as.character(help('['))` gives (on my windows machine) `"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.2/library/base/help/Extract"`---it solves your `[` vs `Extract` problem. You just need to do a bit more work to get the package version and do a little string substitution. You'll probably want to handle `base` as a special case.

Answer (score 3):

In an R session outside RStudio, typing `help.start()`, clicking on 'Search engine & keywords' and searching for, e.g., `xtabs` results in a listing that includes `stats::xtabs`; clicking on that link opens, for me, a url http://127.0.0.1:18412/library/stats/html/xtabs.html. The url consists of the local host `http://127.0.0.1`, a port `18412`, and a path `/library/stats/html/xtabs.html`. The fact that this is an http request on localhost implies that R is running a local http server (started by `help.start()`, also by RStudio on startup).

The port is available (after the help server starts) with

```
> tools:::httpdPort()
[1] 18412
```

The path can be reconstructed from

```
paths = as.character(help('xtabs'))
```

where the path(s) returned indicate which (currently loaded) packages reference `xtabs` and the relevant components (library and term) can be extracted with

```
pattern = paste0(R.home(), "(/library/[^/]+)/help(/.+)")
lib = sub(pattern, "\\1", paths)
term = sub(pattern, "\\2", paths)
```

Thus the url can be constructed as

```
> url = paste0("http://127.0.0.1:", port, lib, "/html", term, ".html")
```

and opened with, e.g.,

```
browseURL(url)
```

There are a number of challenges with this, e.g., when more than one package defines an alias to `xtabs` (so that `paths` and all subsequent steps have multiple elements).

For what it's worth, the individual help pages are *not* by default available directly with R, but rather are created dynamically by the web server. E.g., note that

```
> dir(R.home("library/stats/html"))
[1] "00Index.html" "R.css"
> browseURL(R.home("library/stats/html/00Index.html"))
```

displays the index page, but clicking on the `xtabs` link results in a 404 file not found. Static pages can be generated when R and / or packages are installed with `R CMD INSTALL --html ...`

Comment: rdocumentation isn't official and lags behind R package versions, as noted in a comment I made on another answer to your question.

Comment: This was helpful for me, as I can view the html documentation of a package currently in development

Answer (score 2):

If you want a webpage that gathers help files from several packages and organizes it in some way, I think you are looking for [rdocumentation(dot)org](https://www.rdocumentation.org/). You just have to type what you want in the search bar.

Normally the docs are stored in your computer when you install the packages, that's why there's not a webpage with all of them. They're store locally.

I don't think there's any other place on the internet that does that.

Comment: rdocumentation might be ok for base packages, but contributed packages can be out of date, e.g., dplyr is at version 0.8.3 but rdocumentation has version 0.7.8 from November, 2018. In general different package versions are problematic for linking to R documentation when writing about R.