# View documentation for internal / unexported function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the help docs for function `tools:::httpdPort()` but

```
> ?tools:::httpdPort
No documentation for ‘httpdPort’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??httpdPort’
```

`??httpdPort` returns `No results found`

If we check the autocomplete, we don't see it.

[image]

How exactly do we access the docs/help files for this unexported function?

Comment: HTMLheader **is** exported from tools, that's why you can see it's documentation. Try `?tools::HTMLheader`. Can you see the same thing for `httpdPort`? All functions you see in `tools:::` that have docs are the same ones you would see by just looking at `tools::`, namely the exported ones with documentation.

Comment: Unexported functions are never documented.

Comment: Unexported functions are unexported because they are not intended to be called directly by the end user. There is no need to document them because they are only called by internal code.

Comment: @Roland Martin uses the unexported function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59622958/5783745). I guess the best way to learn about it in this case is to view the source code

Comment: Well, you *can*  use them. Hence, the existence of `:::`. But you *cannot* expect documentation or even expect them to be stable as they are not part of the official API. Unexported functions are internal package code and such code can change without notice when a package gets updated.

Comment: @Roland never say never :) https://blog.r-hub.io/2019/12/12/internal-functions/#how-to-document-internal-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding documentation for unexported (internal) functions:

- It's **not typical** for unexported functions to be documented, [although they still can be](https://blog.r-hub.io/2019/12/12/internal-functions/#how-to-document-internal-functions)
- You can always look for the source code to see if the author provided information (for users, but also for other developers). In the case of `tools:::httpdPort()`, it doesn't have any documentation in the [R source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/tools/R/dynamicHelp.R#L603-L611). Look for documentation for which manual pages weren't created, but also keep an eye out for developer comments in the actual source code. There is also a chance of finding other contextual files in the github repository, so check for any extraneous files.